# Performance issue with a new Visio instance

Tags: excel, vba, visio

i would like to start a new Visio instance out of excel and execute some code.
This works well, but it takes about 100x times longer to execute the code than executing the code directly in a visio macro.

Visio 2003

```
Dim visio_app As New Visio.Application
Dim doc As Visio.Document, pg As Visio.page

Set doc = visio_app.Documents.Open(.......)
Set pg = visio_app.ActivePage

'Performance problem runing this methode
delete.doDeleteDeleted visio_app, pg

......
```

No Performance issue when i start the code directly in visio

```
delete.doDeleteDeleted Application, Application.ActivePage
```

does anybody knows how to fix it?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is this delete.doDeleteDeleted method?  Is that a routine you have in VBA in Excel, that you can run in Visio as well?

Comment: Yes, it runs in visio as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found a workaround. I created a visio file which includes the doDeleteDeleted methode and a run sub which executes doDeleteDeleted. Then I use visio_app.**ExecuteLine**(....) to execute the code in the Visio file. This works, but its unattractive